# Apostrophe Sitemap Database configuration

Tags: node.js, apostrophe-cms

I have implemented the module apostrophe-site-map and the sitemap xmls are generating as per locale. Following is my module configuration

```
'apostrophe-site-map': {
    // array of doc types you do NOT want
    // to include, even though they are
    // accessible on the site.
    excludeTypes: [],
    perLocale: true,
    piecesPerBatch: 100
}
```

I have kept 2 scripts in package.json as follows:

```
"generate-site-map": "node src/app apostrophe-site-map:map --indent --file",
"update-site-map-cache": "node src/app apostrophe-site-map:map --update-cache"
```

So I am able to generate sitemap xmls for each locale using the script `generate-site-map` and I wanted to try the caching part so I kept `update-site-map-cache` also.

Now on our demo server we are getting MongoDB connection error **for the second command(update cache)**. The error is:

`MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
  at Pool.<anonymous>`

So basically it is trying to find a local MongoDB service while updating cache. There is not local setup of MongoDB on our server as its all in MongoDB Atlas.

**My questions is that, Is there a way to specify the host of the database in the config for apostrophe-site-map?**

Answer (score 1):

`apostrophe-site-map` does not create its own database connection. It uses the model layer methods provided by Apostrophe, and thus reuses the standard one.

So your question is really, "why doesn't my command line task talk to the right database?"

And the answer is "because you are not setting the same `APOS_MONGODB_URI` environment variable when running the task as you set when running the actual site." It's also possible you're using a `data/local.js` file to override and set the URI for MongoDB, but the solution is the same: be consistent between the environment where the site runs and the environment where the task runs.

Comment: Okay, I got you. We don't have the variable `APOS_MONGODB_URI` in our project. The variable name for the MongoDB URI is `MONGODB` which is set in our CI yaml. I will try setting value for `APOS_MONGODB_URI` and update here if it solves my issue.

Comment: We were missing our MongoDb URL in environment. That was the mistake.